# Finding python operator for every tool within Blender

Tags: python

To calculate an oriented bounding box as defined [here](http://www.mechcore.net/files/docs/alg/gottschalk00collision.pdf). I need the convex hull of an object. I know that there is an operator in Blender to do this, since you can go to edit mode, press spacebar and type "convex hull".
However, I have been unable to figure out how to call this operator from python. I know that one can usually find a python operator by hovering over the respective UI element one uses to invoke the operation from the interface, but that does not work in the spacebar-search.

Therefore:
Does anybody know of a reliable way to find the python operator for each tool within Blender?

Comment: We had a number of similar questions, but asking how to access a specific tool isn't a very good question, better ask how to find the Python operator for _any_ tool.

Comment: I thought I knew how to find the Python operator in general (by hovering over the UI element used to invoke it from the interface) but that does not seem to work for the spacebar-search. I guess I could rephrase my question and ask how to find the python operator for a tool listed in the spacebar-search?

Comment: Yep, that would be best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pull down the main menu an area appears which shows the log of invoked operators (I don't know the name of this area).

[image]

There you can find operators which are not displayed in tooltips.